# Laravel Pagination merge

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, pagination, laravel-pagination

I'm using laravel 4 for my project .
I have paginated select results from 4 tables and I wanted to pass them to view in one variable .

```
$vehicles = DB::table('vehicle')->orderBy('postTime','DESC')->paginate(8);
$estates = DB::table('estate')->orderBy('postTime','DESC')->paginate(8);
$tradings = DB::table('trading')->orderBy('postTime','DESC')->paginate(8);
$jobs = DB::table('job')->orderBy('postTime','DESC')->paginate(8);
```

but I could not merge them using **`array_merge()`** . I also tried `->to_array()` after paginate, it didn't work.

can some one help me here ?

**EDIT**

as @Turgut Sarıçam suggested , I used `getItems()` for my results and here is my code :

```
public static function index(){
    $minVehicle = DB::table('vehicle')->min('price');
    $maxVehicle = DB::table('vehicle')->max('price');
    $minEstate = DB::table('estate')->min('price');
    $maxEstate = DB::table('estate')->max('price');
    $minTrading = DB::table('trading')->min('price');
    $maxTrading = DB::table('trading')->max('price');
    if($minVehicle == 'توافقی')
        $minVehicle = 0;
    if($maxVehicle == 'توافقی')
        $maxVehicle = 0;
    if($minEstate == 'توافقی')
        $minEstate = 0;
    if($maxEstate == 'توافقی')
        $maxEstate = 0;
    if($minTrading == 'توافقی')
        $minTrading = 0;
    if($maxTrading == 'توافقی')
        $maxTrading = 0;
    $vehicles = DB::table('vehicle')->orderBy('postTime','DESC')->paginate(8);
    $estates = DB::table('estate')->orderBy('postTime','DESC')->paginate(8);
    $tradings = DB::table('trading')->orderBy('postTime','DESC')->paginate(8);
    $jobs = DB::table('job')->orderBy('postTime','DESC')->paginate(8);
    $allResults = array_merge($vehicles,$jobs);
    //echo "<meta charset='UTF8'><pre>";
    //return die(print_r($allResults));
    return View::make('search')->with(
        array(
            'minVehicle' => $minVehicle,
            'maxVehicle' => $maxVehicle,
            'minEstate' => $minEstate,
            'maxEstate' => $maxEstate,
            'minTrading' => $minTrading,
            'maxTrading' => $maxTrading,
            'ads' => $allResults
        )
    );
}
```

Dumping $allResults (where I commented) had some results.
I cant show the exact result , but here is example of it :

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 243
        [tableName] => vehicle
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 239
        [tableName] => vehicle
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 235
        [tableName] => vehicle
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 231
        [tableName] => vehicle
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 227
        [tableName] => vehicle
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 223
        [tableName] => vehicle
    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 219
        [tableName] => vehicle
    )

[7] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 215
        [tableName] => vehicle
    )

[8] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 4
        [tableName] => job
    )

[9] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 3
        [tableName] => job
    )

)
```

although the result seems to be fair , no view was returned . just a blank white page

Comment: Can you copy your code instead of having a screenshot for it?

Comment: Sure . look at edit 2

Comment: What was the result of die(print_r($allResults))

Comment: @MwaaJoseph added to question body;

Comment: Try then to pass $allResults->toArray();

Comment: Also please note that any form of merging would get rid of the pagination

Comment: Sry , My mistake . I entered wrong code to my question body , check it again . 

and I will try what u suggested and tell you results soon.

Comment: omg ! if merging will get rid of the pagination , then I should die !!! I could use nothing after `->pagitaion(8)` and get result for one table . no need for `->toAray()` or anything else. Then what should I do to have all results ? :(

Answer (score 0):

You should get the items first. Try like this:

```
$allResults = array_merge($vehicles->items(), $estates->items(), $tradings->items(), $jobs->items());
```

Edit: I guess you can get items with [getItems()](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.html#method_getItems) function in Laravel 4. Above is for Laravel 5, my bad.

Comment: Well, I just tried this in Laravel 5 and it works. When you paginate the query, the returning value is not an array. It is a Paginator instance. You need arrays in order to be able to merge them via array_merge.

Comment: Well, after using getItems() , laravel does not generate a view . its just a blank white page , no errors . I tried passing $allResults and even one results such as $vehicles->items() and this happened .

Comment: You can pass the variable to a view like this: `return view('your_view_file')->with('allResults', $allResults)` and then get the results from your view like this `@foreach($allResults as $result) {{ var_dump($result) }} @endforeach`

Comment: I know that part . I used assosiative array in `->with()` and it works fine on other passed variables . but when I pass $allResults , I get blank page.

Comment: Did you try dumping $allResults? Is it really empty?

Comment: Look at my edit .
FYI : I tried , its not empty . although if it was empty , there had to be a view with other stuff in it.

My view has more things but when I pass $allResults it just returns blank

Comment: If it is a valid array, then I don't think $allResults is the problem here, since it is just an array of objects. My last suggestion would be trying this with a view having only $allResults in it.

Comment: Its not completely valid . I added it to my question body .

Comment: You added collection merge method's results. Could you please add the results for array_merge?

Comment: Sry , My mistake . check it again

Comment: me too ! but no views are returned !

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with collections that are returned from the query. Don't think array merge is correct way to go Try using collection merge.

Collection merge is supported as well in laravel 4. 
Try using this

```
$merged_collection = $vehicles->merge($estates)->merge($tradings)->merge($jobs);
```

Comment: I'm using laravel 4.2 . I could not understand the code

Comment: The variable merged_collection will contain all the other collections. You can view complete list of collection methods here http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html

Comment: I've never used Collection actually . can you give me an example how it works in my situation ?

Comment: Well that didnt work too . same problem I faced while trying Turgut Sarıçam answer . it returns blank page . also , merge is not known as true method in my IDM suggestions and it labled;